# Auto generate alpha numeric in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm currently working on my project for which I used VB.NET 2019 and SQL server. I need to create a function which auto generates IDs.

I want my IDs to be like these: `P001`, `P002`, `P003` etc. Can someone show me how to code it? Below is my code

```
 Private Sub Form4_Load_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BindData()
    Dim data As String = "Data Source=LAPTOP-M8KKSG0I;Initial Catalog=Oceania;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(data)
    Try
        If Con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()

        End If

        Dim sql As String = "Select Max(PatientID) from Patient"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        Dim Max As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        If Max > 0 Then
            TextBox1.Text = Max + 1
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = "P01"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. It's up to you to research, think and make your best effort to implement. If it doesn't work, then you can post a question here, show us what you've done and explain how it doesn't meet your expectations. In this case, the clue is that the only part that changes is the number, so you're not generating the alpha part at all.

Comment: I suggest you look at `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` to start with, and then computed columns. If you're stuck, then show us where your stuck, and the code you've written. Otherwise show us the research you've done and explain what you don't understand about it. Also, you should consider what happens with you get to `'P999'`.

Comment: I request you to check my answer.

Comment: (Conversion from string P04 to type 'integer' is not valid) System pop out this message. how should i do

Comment: @jiayukoh Create a column PatientID of int identity and another column PatientCode Varchar(10) for the P001, P002, etc. Otherwise, you need to extract 4 from P004. The best option is to go with the computed column as suggested in my answer.

Comment: @jiayukoh You can accept the answer see how at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try like this. Here `1` is an auto-generated number that may be an identity key column value from a table in SQL Server.

```
Dim number As Integer = 1
Dim numberText As String = "P" & number.ToString().PadLeft(3, "0")
```

Live [demo](https://rextester.com/l/visual_basic_online_compiler)

You can add a computed column like this in your table for auto-generating the sequences. This will reduce the chances of duplicate value runtime once more than one person will do the entry simultaneously.

```
Alter table Patient ADD PatientCode AS ('P' + Convert(Varchar(3),CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 3 - LEN(PatientID)), PatientID)) )
```

To get the column value dynamically you can try the below code to generate function.

```
Private Sub GenerateSequnce()
    Dim constring As String = "Data Source=TestServer;Initial Catalog=TestDB;User id = TestUser;password=test@123"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Top 1 ISNULL(TaxCode, 0) from Tax_Mst Order By TaxCode Desc", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    Dim maxNumberCode = dt.Rows(0)("TaxCode").ToString()
                    If (maxNumberCode = "0") Then
                        maxNumberCode = "1"
                    End If

                    Dim numberText As String = "P" & maxNumberCode.ToString().PadLeft(3, "0")
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Here the column `TaxCode` is `int` with `identity` constraint.

With the minor correction in your code, you can achieve this as shown below.

```
Dim data As String = "Data Source=LAPTOP-M8KKSG0I;Initial Catalog=Oceania;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(data)
        Try
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If

            Dim sql As String = "Select ISNULL(Max(PatientID), 0) from Patient"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
            Dim Max As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar

            If (Max = "0") Then
                Max = "1"
            Else
                Max = CInt(Max) + 1
            End If
            Dim numberText As String = "P" & Max.ToString().PadLeft(3, "0")
            TextBox1.Text = numberText

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description)
       End Try
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: "Here `1` is an auto-generated number that may be an identity key column value from a table in SQL Server." - What? It's a variable in your code. How does your code generate `P002`, `P003`, etc?

Comment: @Enigmativity I have taken number as a variable because these numbers will come from datatable after executing SQL Command as - Dim number As String  = dataTable.Rows(0)("Col1").ToString()

Comment: *"numbers will come from datatable after executing SQL Command"* How are you avoiding race conditions with this?

Comment: @Larnu I didn't get you. I have just provided an answer on how to generate sequences if you already know the number.

Comment: So where is that number coming from then, @SurajKumar ? If the OP is auto  generating this value (presumably on `INSERT`) how do you know what the "next" number is?

Comment: @SurajKumar - Where did you get the requirement that the number comes from the database? If you assume, though, that it does, then you should show that in your answer. Defining `number` like that is misleading.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have updated my answer to get column value from the table.

Comment: @Larnu I have updated my answer to get column value from the table.

Comment: So I go back to my original question: *"How are you avoiding race conditions with this?"*

Comment: @Larnu Can you elaborate more on your concern?

Comment: @SurajKumar Not sure how I can elaborate more. You are familiar with what a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) is, no? They're quite fundamental in the RDBMS and programming world.

Comment: @Larnu I know if more than one person will do an entry at a time then there may be a chance of duplicate so I had only suggested generating the sequence not when to generate. For maintaining that a computed column can work which is another topic of discussion when to call this function?

Comment: So you *aren't* handling race conditions, @SurajKumar . That, alone, is likely a reason for the downvotes you've received, in my opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210216/discussion-between-suraj-kumar-and-larnu).